# CSS not rendering while converting webpage to pdf using convertApi.dll

Tags: asp.net, convertapi

I have a large pdf with 50-60 pages. I converted the pdf into web page using [ConvertApi web2pdf](http://www.convertapi.com/web-pdf-api) online api and then added some input controls on the pages wherever required.

When user filled all the required input and submit I rendered the entire page and show the preview to the user to check whether user has filled the inputs correctly. After that when User click submit then it stores into database and generate the pdf of the same.

I used convertApi.dll and wrote the following code to generate pdf.

```
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
Web2Pdf convertApi;
convertApi = new Web2Pdf();
convertApi.SetPageSize("A4");
convertApi.SetPageWidth("100%");
convertApi.ConvertHtml(HtmlText, outStream);
```

My problem is when we generate the pdf it does not take all the styles used in the page. And pdf look different. I need to provide the very similar pdf which client provided. Can any one suggest me to do it in better way.
Thanks.

Comment: The ConvertApi Web2Pdf converter use WebKit to create PDF files. Please test your HTML file for error and validity at http://validator.w3.org/